# Exempting Coldfusion page from authentication

Tags: coldfusion, session-variables, coldfusion-9

I need to post from a non-secure CF page to a secure CF page. I don't want to have to go through and implement the user authentication on the page sending the values because its a rather cumbersome process due to the way this legacy site was setup and secondly because the page sending the values is acting as a service between two unrelated order management systems as opposed to a user.

Right now, when I try to post to, the response result is a redirect to the login of the homepage. Is there a way to make an exception for a posting or receiving page from forcing user authentication?

I'm using `<cfhttp>` to post the values to post page which has a series of `<cfparam>'s` that I'm passing the values to. Once I pass those values into the post page is when the post page triggers a redirect to the home page because the post page is an internal page in the order management system and is displayed as a client logs in and a session is created for them.

Comment: How is the post handled right now, i.e. **what** redirects to the login page? Is it a function, is it an include, is it handled in the onRequest/onRequestStart event of the Application.cfc?

Comment: From what I can tell, its in the Application.cfc. Each page in the system looks for a clientID, userID, but the session variables are set in the Application.cfc file. It runs a isDefined function to see if userID is set. If it is and type is client, it looks for companyID on the client. If none of those are set, it sets a url redirect to the home page to force the person to log in, but if its set, then it continues the order processing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any code, here is a guess what it might look like and how you could add an exception for specific requests:

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" output="false" returnType="boolean">

    <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required="true">

    <!--- treat initialized SESSION or matching request token (rtoken) as successful authentication --->
    <cfset LOCAL.isAuthenticated = (
        isDefined("SESSION.userID")
            or
        ( structKeyExists(FORM, "rtoken") and (FORM["rtoken"] eq "some-secret-only-you-know") )
    )>

    <cfif LOCAL.isAuthenticated>

        <!--- do something... --->

    <!--- not authenticated --->
    <cfelse>

        <!--- redirect to login --->
        <cflocation url="login.cfm" statusCode="303" addToken="false">

    </cfif>

</cffunction>
```

Now you could simple add the key-value-pair `rtoken=some-secret-only-you-know` (i.e. `<input type="hidden" name="rtoken" value="some-secret-only-you-know" />`) to your POST to bypass the session based authentification.
Disclaimer: Only use this method if the POST parameters (form fields) are *not* public/editable by the user.

Feel free to provide actual context so I can assist in a more concrete way.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a couple of apps with similar, but not identical requirements.  Here is how I handled those requirements in the last one I wrote.  All this code is the Application.cfc file in the methods specified.

In onApplicationStart:

```
application.securityNotNeededPages = 
"somePage.cfm,someOtherPage.cfm,someMorePages.cfm";
```

In onRequestStart

```
var ThisPage = listlast(cgi.PATH_INFO, "/");
...
if (ListFindNoCase(application.securityNotNeededPages, ThisPage) is false) {
security related code
}
else {
code for when the page does not to be secured
}
```

Comment: I often do similar process. I prefer storing the pages as an array rather than a list.